# How to ask the user to enter numbers and then sum the numbers which are divisible by 3?

Tags: python

I want to make a Python script which has the user enter 7 numbers and then check which numbers can be divided by 3, then sum those numbers, and show it to the user as "sum=xx".

I tried:

```
input_string = input("Enter a list element separated by space ")
list  = input_string.split()
```

Comment: What are you having trouble with?

Comment: `print(f'sum={sum(int(x) for x in list if int(x)%3==0)}')`

Answer (score 1):

Here is using list comprehension,

```
input_string = input("Enter a list element separated by space ")
numbers  = [int(num) for num in input_string.split(',') if int(num) % 3 == 0]
print('Sum = {}'.format(sum(numbers)))
```

This is based on your question above.

But, you also said that you would want user to input 7 numbers and find sum for numbers which are divisible by 3.

Here is other simple example, where we ask user to input 7 numbers, one number at a time and print sum at the end.

```
all_numbers = []

for i in range(7):
    num = int(input(f'Enter number {i + 1}:\n1'))
    all_numbers.append(num)

sum_of_numbers = sum([num for num in all_numbers if num % 3 == 0])
print(f'Sum = {sum_of_numbers}')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of integers from the input using the [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) function which gives you an integer object from a string, since the split function only gives you a list of separated strings.

```
input_string = input("Enter a list element separated by space ")
my_list = input_string.split()
numbers = []
for n in my_list:
    numbers.append(int(n))
```

However, this will throw a ValueError if `n` is not a valid number (e.g. `"a"`), which you can catch with a [`try`-`except`statement](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions).

Notice how I changed the name of your variable to `my_list` because the name `list` already has a meaning in Python and it's a good practice to not assign it to a variable.

If you want to do it in a single step, you can use the useful `map` function to apply the `int` function to all of the elements in `list`. You can check the documentation for this function, as well as any other on the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map), or using the `help` built-in function. (e.g. `help(map)`)

```
numbers = map(int, my_list)
```

---

You can then check if there are 7 numbers in the list by using the [`len`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) function, and if there aren't 7 you can prompt the user to input the numbers again if that is what you want to do.

```
>>> my_list = [1, 2, 3]
>>> len(my_list) == 3
True
```

If you want to keep prompting the user until there are seven numbers on your list, you can put the prompt inside a `while` block, like shown:

```
numbers = [] # We create an empty list
while len(numbers) != 7:
    input_string = input("Enter a list element separated by space ")
    my_list = input_string.split()
    numbers = list(map(int, my_list)) # Get the numbers
```

---

After getting the numbers, you can see which ones are divisible by 3 by using the [modulo](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations) operator, which gives you the rest of dividing a number by another (3 in your case). Some examples:

```
>>> 7%3  #  7 = 3*2 + 1
1
>>> 19%5 # 14 = 5*3 + 4
4
>>> 8%4  #  8 = 4*2 + 0
0
```

Since you want to check which numbers of your list are divisible by 3 you can check whether this module is 0 or not inside of a loop through the list.

If the numbers are divisible by 3, you can add them to a counting variable, you could initialize to 0 before the loop. That way, after the loop you'd get the sum you want in this variable.

Another, more elegant way of doing so is using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) instead of a loop, which would only retain the numbers divisible by 3, and then sum its elements using the [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) function.

```
new_list = [x for x in numbers if x%3 == 0]
sum = sum(new_list)
```

Comment: Two things: 1. This shadows the `list` class; 2. This doesn't account for the "7 numbers"

Comment: And also, there's a high chance this is homework, [which does both you and the OP more harm than good](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/2343935).

Comment: while len(numbers) != 7:

Comment: My bad. I forgot to convert the map into a list again. I've edited that part so now it should work.